# Entity framework don't delete records but fill column

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to change the way EF works with deleting records.
Instead of deleting the row in the database it should fill a column (GCColumn or so).

When retrieving data it should always filter on GCColumn IS NULL + the filter you apply.

Anyone know if this is achievable and how ?

Comment: so it is actually an update not delete ? and for select a predefined filter . Show me what have you tried so far

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I was wondering if there is an solution for this out of the box. I'm thinking to add EFHooks and fix it with that.

Comment: but why now to use approach provided by EF. Why to complicate the system if you have already a solution which In this case is simple asw ell

Comment: well, you could revert certain actions when the data is still available in the database. Now i think about it, maybe I shouldnt fix it like this..

Comment: That's called a [soft delete](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/soft-deleting-entities-cleanly-using-entity-framework-6-interceptors.html)

Comment: I have answered with focus on retrieval. I don't think it is possible to use DbSet.Remove(<entity>) and have EF translate this to and update of the GCColumn. I would recommend using the repository pattern and implement Remove() methods, abstracting the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addition to my answer above, consider the case in which many or even all of your entities have this GCColumn.

You could start with a base entity for these pseudo-deletable entities:

```
public abstract class PseudoDeletable
{
    public DateTime GCColumn { get; set;}
}
```

and have entities defined as:

```
public class Order : PseudoDeletable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    // etc.
}
```

Then, you could create a generic base repository

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : PseudoDeletable
{
    protected IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; }

    public RepositoryBase()
    {
        DbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> RemoveDeleted
    {
        get { return e => e.GCColumn == null; }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
        expression = expression.And(RemoveDeleted);
        return DbSet.Where(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

and have derived repositories, like:

```
public class OrderRepository : RepositoryBase<Order>
{
}
```

The `GetAll` method can then be called like this:

```
new orderRepository().GetAll(x => x.ProductId == 1);
```

and it will just return orders that have not been deleted.

Please note that you'll have an issue with [entity includes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) for related records: how to include only un-deleted related entities, but that is a consequence of you desire to keep 'deleted' records in the database.

Comment: Thanks, ill try and implement this!

Answer (score 0):

In one project we use the repository pattern for database access and each entity has its own repository.

It is a multi-tenant database and we use the type of filter you are looking for to filter entities accessible to the current user, not to filter for a delete flag, but the method could be used analogously.

Each repository that needs filtering, gets a filter method:

```
private Expression<Func<Order, bool>> RemoveDeleted
{
    get
    {
        return order => order.GCColumn == null;
    }
}
```

Then, add an expression to each repository method, like:

```
public override IEnumerable<Order> GetAll(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> expression)
{
    expression = expression.And(RemoveDeleted);
    return DbSet.Where(expression).ToList();
}
```

(*The extension method `Add` comes from a set of [ExpressionExtensions](https://gist.github.com/NotMyself/1a4614851aabc305eece).*)

Now, you can use expressions like:

```
orderRepository.GetAll(x => x.ProductId == productId);
```

and

```
orderRepository.GetAll(x => x.OrderDate >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1));
```

So now you business logic can have many methods using the same GetAll() methods, with different filters, but doesn't have to care about 'deleted' entities. But you are still responsible for creating a correct filter for each repository method.

If the delete flag is not in all entities, but the delete status is registered in another entity, you can do the following:

```
private Expression<Func<Order, bool>> RemoveDeleted
{
    get
    {
        return orderLine => orderLine.Order.GCColumn == null;
    }
}
```

In this example orders are deleted in whole, not individual lines in it.

Comment: As a safe guard, you could apply the method described in [Tutorial: Web app with a multi-tenant database using Entity Framework and Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security), provided you use SQL Server 2016 or above.